# basic `StyleDefinitions` question: setting cell `Backgroun` when printing

Tags: stylesheet

I am having trouble getting good `StyleData` guidance from the Mma docs.  Am I overlooking the good stuff?  Anyway, suppose I run the following in a notebook:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
 StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData[All, "Printout"], ShowCellLabel -> False],
    Cell[StyleData["Input", "Printout"], CellFrame -> True],
    Cell[StyleData["Output", "Printout"], 
         CellMargins -> {{100, 100}, {10, 10}}],
    Cell[StyleData["Output", "Printout"], 
         CellDingbat -> "\[FilledCircle]"],
    Cell[StyleData["Output", "Printout"], Background -> Yellow]
    }]
 ]
```

Now to see the result I do this:

```
Export["c:\\temp\\temp.pdf", EvaluationNotebook[], "PDF"];
```

When I examine the document, I don't see the dingbats or the background color.  Should I?

Btw, this is not a request for comment on the horrible style.  I just want to understand why I'm not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 separate definitions for "Output" so only the first one will be used therefore the 2nd and 3rd that contain the dingbat and background are ignored.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
 StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData[All, "Printout"], ShowCellLabel -> False],
    Cell[StyleData["Input", "Printout"], CellFrame -> True],
    Cell[StyleData["Output", "Printout"], 
    CellMargins -> {{100, 100}, {10, 10}},
    CellDingbat -> "\[FilledCircle]",
    Background -> Yellow]
    }]
 ]
```

Comment: Got it.  Where in the documentation should I have found this information?  (I find the StyleData docs to be useless.)

Comment: it is not explicit in the docs as far as I am aware but a general principle of Mma is that only the first occurrence of options is used and even though these are style definitions rather than options the same principle applies