# programmatically styling notebook

Tags: stylesheet

A notebook's background can be changed simply by

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Background -> GrayLevel[.9]];
```

What is the command to set, let's say, the background color of all Section cells, that is, to programmatically edit stylesheets ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Section"], Background -> Yellow]}]]
```

Code extracted from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92406/5467).

It doesn't edit the style sheet (I mean the file "default.nb") but add new style informations that are saved in the current notebook (the EvaluationNotebook[])

Comment: This is very poorly documented. Can't find anything neither comprehensive nor concise. Only pieces of informations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It seems exactly what I was looking for. The options I can set are all those listed by 'Cell // Options // Sort // TableForm',
are they ?

Comment: @mitochondrial I think that all options listed by `Cell // Options` can be set in this way. Maybe there are other options. Personally, I sometimes use the options inspector to find and set the proper option interactively, and then I insert it in my code.